# How do I force apply a dark theme on Android?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force_dark), I only need to set `android:forceDarkAllowed=true` in my activity manifest and inherit theme from `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"`. I tried that, but it didn't work.

Here's my manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:forceDarkAllowed="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here's my `styles.xml` styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    ...
</style>
```

I tried to get the theme name of the activity by using this code below:

```
resources.getResourceName(
    packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        .applicationInfo.theme
)
```

It shows me `com.example.name:style/AppTheme` and not `AppTheme.Dark`. How can I make it so that when I run the application, the `MainActivity` automatically sets itself to use `AppTheme.Dark` (i.e. dark mode) using `android:forceDarkAllowed`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is not how [dark mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) works on Android 10.

First, Android does not magically append `.Dark` to your theme at any point, regardless of whether or not the user enabled dark mode. You have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. So, Android will use `AppTheme` all the time, and your `AppTheme.Dark` will not be used.

Second, the idea behind `DayNight` is that you use that as you base theme all the time, and Android will switch between normal and dark modes based on user request. So, if you switch `AppTheme` to extend `DayNight`, and get rid of `AppTheme.Dark`, you will be matching what [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) calls for.

`android:forceDarkAllowed` is for cases where you are not in position to use a `DayNight` theme, and you want Android to try to automatically convert your UI to a dark theme. If you wanted to keep `AppTheme` extending `Light` instead of `DayNight`, this might work (I personally have not tried it with a `MaterialComponents` theme). But, even then, it will only be when the user has enabled dark mode (e.g., tapped on the notification shade tile).

For example, in [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/blob/vFINAL/TypeInfo), I use `DayNight` for my theme:

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

I have different definitions for those colors in [`res/values/`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/blob/vFINAL/TypeInfo/src/main/res/values/colors.xml) and [`res/values-night/`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/blob/vFINAL/TypeInfo/src/main/res/values-night/colors.xml). I do not use `forceDarkAllowed`. And, when the user toggles night mode, my UI goes from:

[image: DayNight normal]

to:

[image: DayNight dark mode]

> How can I make it so that when I run the application, the MainActivity automatically sets itself to use AppTheme.Dark (i.e. dark mode) using android:forceDarkAllowed?

You don't.

If you want a dark theme all the time, use a regular theme (not `Light`, not `DayNight`).

Comment: Thank you! I love your very thorough explanation. I knew that I can change to dark theme programmatically and upon user request. However, I got really confused about that `android:forceDarkAllowed` section. I will try rereading it again to see if I missed anything. Thank you, really. This is perfect.

Comment: @Richard: `android:forceDarkAllowed` is mostly for existing apps that want to try to hack in dark mode support without reworking their themes and UIs. It works surprisingly well, but it still makes mistakes. You would need to thoroughly test your app to confirm that the auto-conversion does not make some stuff ugly or unusable.

Comment: Ah I see. I tested `android:forceDarkAllowed` on the style `Theme.AppCompat` and `Theme.MaterialComponents` and it worked as you stated. It magically converts the colour to a dark-theme mode. I then tried it again on `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight/Light` and `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light/DayNight`, and it didn't work.

Comment: I read this line `First, Android does not magically append .Dark to your theme at any point` and immediately reached the conclusion that this answer is from CommonsWare.

Comment: is there a way to customize "forceDarkAllowed" tints?

Comment: @PavelPoley: I am not aware of any options for that, but I have not researched that point.

Answer (score 7):

1. If your app uses a dark theme (such as Theme.Material), Force Dark will **NOT** be applied. Similarly, if your app's theme inherits from a DayNight theme, Force Dark will **NOT** be applied, due to the automatic theme switching.
2. Dark theme is available in Android 10 (API level 29) and higher. Make sure that your device's API level is 29 + that your target SDK in the `gradle` is 29.
3. There are two ways to apply dark theme:

   1. DayNight - custom-able theme - you control how dark/light theme will look like
   2. Force dark - you control the light theme, and if the user chooses dark mode the system will convert your views to dark theme at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

There are settings to allow dynamically setting day or night regardless of the current system setting.

> Each of the options map directly to one of the AppCompat.DayNight
> modes:
>
> ```
> Light - MODE_NIGHT_NO
> Dark - MODE_NIGHT_YES
> System default - MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
> ```
>
> To switch the theme, call AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode().

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#change-themes

This would apply to setting a DayNight theme. If you are trying to take advantage of the Force Dark in Android 10, it applies to the `.Light` sub-themes. It will not be applied to any of the `DayNight` or inherently dark themes.

> Apps must opt-in to Force Dark by setting
> android:forceDarkAllowed="true" in the activity's theme. This
> attribute is set on all of the system and AndroidX provided light
> themes, such as Theme.Material.Light.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force-dark

Below that, the documentation also specifies how to exclude certain items, either in resources or code.

> Force Dark can be controlled on specific views with the
> android:forceDarkAllowed layout attribute or with
> setForceDarkAllowed().

Beyond that, there are ways to detect the current system light / dark setting and respond to it using the options above, but that is for another post.

It's not a great solution for a dark theme and I apologize for any overlap with the accepted answer, but I do not agree with claiming something isn't possible because it isn't preferred.

Comment: This is a very nice, underrated answer!